# hibernate.cfg.xml to java configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to create a sample hibernate program, i have working code of xml based hibernate configurations so trying to convert it in annotation and java configuration based.
i successfully converted Employee.hbm.xml to annotation (@Entity in Employee.class) but not able to do same for hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
Configuration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration().addAnnotatedClass(com.hibernate.apple.Employee.class);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost/DataBase");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","xxx");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","xxx");
Session s = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    t.begin();
....
```

but its giving error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

above code is to replace the hibernate.hbm.xml , then why it is asking for the same , am i missing something?.

Answer (score 0):

You call the method `configure` and its documentation gives following information:

*Use the mappings and properties specified in an application resource named hibernate.cfg.xml.*

If you don't want to use this file, create your session without calling `configure`.

```
Session s = cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
```

By the way, `AnnotationConfiguration` is from Hibernate 3. Hibernate 4 and 5 do not have this class and therefore think about [updating](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-the-type-annotationconfiguration-is-deprecated/) your current hibernate version.